# When I make a vector of a parent class, if I put a child there, child's members will be lost?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, vector

(Sorry if this question was asked here before, but I searched for it for hours now, and couldn't find anything. Someone said that what I want is possible, and he told me how, I did as he said yet it is total failure.)

First of all, here is a class diagram for the easier presenting of the question.

[image: Class diagram for my problem]

Then the code which doesn't do what I want:

```
int main()
{
    Employee jack("Jack", 100);
    People guys(jack);             // using push_back 
...
}
```

So when this happens, as the debug mode shows, guys[0] will only have a `name`, no `salary`. **Is it even possible, to an object in the vector to have other members than `name`?** Or my only choice is to make an `Employee` vector?

Edit: `Person` is virtual by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vector needs to be of type `vector<Person*>` (or better yet, one of the smart pointer types like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`) in order to do this. Otherwise, the `Employee` will be sliced into a `Person` when it is added, as you are seeing.

Vlad from Moscow's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23662799/3549027) explains why this is the case.

Comment: Thank you, this piece of information saved me a lot of time and going to make my program more elegant. Thank you again.

Comment: If this is obvious to you I apologize, but if you're switching to pointers, make sure something is keeping the pointed-to objects alive, or you'll end up with an even bigger problem.

Comment: Yes, of course, that was not a problem. Now I'm stuck with that I need to get the type of an element in the vector. So to find something that will return a char* "Employee".

Comment: That's another subject, but you can use `dynamic_cast`. But even better is to design so it's not necessary. Here's a link to another question that discusses that subject a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23569140/3549027

Comment: Actually I have to get something to save to a file, but I think I just create an char* `Employee::getType()` method. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 3):

The polymorphism works with pointers and references to base classes. You may not define a vector of references but you may define a vector of pointers to a base class.

Relative to your example vector people should be defined as

```
std::vector<Person *> people;
```